# script and code validation in input field and output it to code by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a comment form which dynamically output content in html element. after that it add the data in database via ajax. The problem is when anyone type and enter submit then it execute the code immediately because it insert the data to html element by jquery. I want to output the code in the html element and not execute the code. I also want to output as code typed inside the input field.

```html
<div id="data-content"></div>
<input type="text" data-event="submit-message">
```

```js
<script> alert('abc'); </script>
```

If anyone type the above alert script in input field it execute the code. I want it to output the code in #data-content element and not execute.

```js
<script>
;(function ($) {
 $(document).ready(function () {
  $("body").on("keyup", "[data-event=\"submit-message\"]", function (e) {
   if(e.keyCode == 13) {
    var Message = $(this).val();
    $('#data-content').append(Message);
   }
  })
 });
}(jQuery));
</script>
```

So I need to validate var Message = $(this).val();
How do I do that?

Comment: please add relevant code

Comment: please provide more information

Comment: Please see the edited question detail.